# What are the "rules" of Cavalier and military oblique projections?

Tags: projection

I am trying to learn the "rules" of the different types of orthographic projections.

For example:

[image]

The above adequately/simply explains the rules of trimetric, dimetric and isometric axonometric projections.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a nice info graphic that explains the rules of the different types of oblique projections.

The following is my best educated guess:

> [image]
>
> **Cavalier Left rules:**
>   • Two equal axes & angles
>   • Angles A & B are equal
>   • Corners MY and MZ are equal in length
>
> **Cavalier Right Rules:**
>   • Two equal axes & angles
>   • Angles A & C are equal
>   • Corners MX and MY are equal in length
>
> **Military Rules:**
>   • Two equal axes & angles
>   • Angles B & C are equal
>   • Corners MX & MZ are equal in length

### Questions:

1. Are my above guesses correct?
2. If not, what are the rules to cavalier and military oblique projections?

I would love some help!

Comment: Those are two particular cases of cavalier projections. In general, they are parallel projections for which the projection direction makes an angle of $\pi/4$ with the viewplane. Lengths of line segments parallel to and perpendicular to the viewplane are unchanged by a cavalier projection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @amd! For some reason I did not get notification that you left a comment (or I missed it). Anyway, +1 for your help!